# Focusrite scarlett solo 2nd gen is detected but not playing sounds

Tags: drivers, sound, soundcard

When I plug my focusrite scarlett solo 2nd gen into my computer it shows up in the ubuntu settings and in pavucontrol. Even when I play something on youtube I can see the audio bar moving.

The issue is that I can hear no sound.

Here are some system screenshots:

[image]

pavucontrol
[image: pavucontrol]

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64 bit.

Comment: Same here with a 2i2, my computer being dual boot I can get sound replugging the soundcard on windows and then go back to ubuntu, but I'll need to go thourgh this again if I unplug the 2i2...